# Agregar datos adicionales a la base de datos creado por MongoDBadapter con Next-Auth

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, nextjs, nextjs13

Estoy trabajando con Next-Auth con el objetivo de crear un sistema de login simple que cuando un usuario se logea cree en una base de datos mongoDB con los datos del usuario(name, mail y imagen).
El codigo usado es el base mostrando en: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/github y https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/mongodb

Hasta aca la aplicacion funciona perfecto, pero lo que quiero hacer es poder crear datos adicionales como articulos que crea el usuario y otras cosas. Como deberia proceder para hacer esto? Mi archivo de conexion a la base de datos mongodb es el siguiente:

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"')
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {}

let client
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local')
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).

  let globalWithMongoClientPromise = global as typeof globalThis & {
    _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;
  };
  if (!globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  console.log(globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise)
  clientPromise = globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise
  console.log(globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise)
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

Estoy atento a cualquier consulta o codigo que necesiten para ayudarme porque no logro encontrar nada en internet que me ayude y chatgpt solo llega hasta nextjs 11 :(